# Not able to understand recursive behaviour in nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to understand how recursive work with a nested js object which may have same key name. For example in the below object the keys are same in nest.
So when I am looping  I am expecting `obj[keys]` will always go the first line(marked as //Line 1).

I am trying to  understand how js will know consider which nest to loop if all the keys have same name. Not sure where I am going wrong in understanding

```js
var obj = {
  a: {         // Line 1
    a: {       // Line 2
      a: {     // Line 3
        sweptArea: 5
      }
    }
  }
}

function loop(obj, keyName) {
  for (var keys in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keys) && typeof obj[keys] === 'object') {
      if (obj[keys][keyName] !== undefined) {
        console.log(obj[keys][keyName])
      } else {
        // In my understanding in all the iteration it will point to obj.a marked as line one
        loop(obj[keys], 'sweptArea')
      }
    }

  }

}

loop(obj, 'sweptArea')
```

Comment: Because `obj` in the `loop` function refers to the `obj` parameter and not the `obj` variable?

Comment: At the top level you are passing `obj` to `loop`. In the first recursive call you are passing `obj.a` too loop. And sure, you are passing `obj.a` *again* in the second recursive call, but that call has its own `obj` parameter with a different value. Looking at the top level you are actually passing `obj.a.a` and so forth.

Comment: It probably doesn't help your understanding that both the outer variable and the parameter are called `obj`.

Comment: I got it . Thanks you for making it clear that obj parameter in function is different in every iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `obj[keys]` is only looks for a key of that name on `obj`. That expression, by itself, does no recursion.

The value passed to the variable defined to the `obj` argument is different each time the function is called.